# How to solve error undefined reference to private_aes()

Tags: c, encryption, undefined-reference

I have used function `Private_aes_encrypt(key,128,&expanded)`  When I type to compile the program with `gcc` by using the following command:

```
gcc -g filename.c filename -lcrypto
```

Then the error `undefined reference to`private_AES_set_encrypt_key`
always comes. How to solve this error??

Comment: I think you have linker problem of some kind. Is `crypto` library (development package) installed on your system?

Answer (score 1):

`private_AES_set_encrypt_key` resides in `libssl` not lib `libcrypto`.

So you want to specify `-lssl` for linking (as well).

Answer (score 1):

Try linking with libcrypto and libssl.